# Define size of long and time_t to 4bytes

Tags: c

I want to synchronize two Raspberry Pi's with a C program. It is working fine, if the program only is running on the Pi's, but for development I want to use my PC (where its also easier to debug), but I send the timespec struct directly as binary over the wire. A raspberry is using 4bytes for long and time_t, my PC is using 8byte each... So they do not come together.

Is it possible to set long and time_t to 4byte each, only for this C script?

I know that the size of long, short, etc. is defined by the system.

Important: I only want to define it once in the script and not transforming it to uintXX or int each time.

Comment: Use uint32_t instead of time_t everywhere?

Comment: C programs are not 'scripts'.  You can't usually change the size of fundamental types.  You might get away with a 32-but compilation instead of a 64-bit compilation, but you should be organizing a proper serialization/deserialization operation, defining the transferred data format so that the wire transfer protocol is clear and clean and not platform-specific.

Comment: @tilz0R timespec is defined with time_t and long. So nothing is changed, if I use uint32_t for everything else!? I have to copy it to a new struct witch define the both vars as uintXX, correct? This I had already but I search for a solution having no time waste (I know it will be not much, but I want as less as possible)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you know how to add 32-bit compilation to cmake?

Comment: Not used cmake seriously enough to know.  In standard make, you might run `make CC='gcc -m32'` or similar.  There's likely a similar mechanism for cmake, but I'm not sure of the ins and outs.  There may also be a completely different and better mechanism than redefining the compiler.  And I assume that CC is used for the linking too.  If not, you need to adjust the linker macro too.

Comment: Some PC compilers use a 32-bit `long`

Comment: Some code would be nice to see what you have done.  Any recommendation on how to achieve the objective of being architecture independent would part from the code you have written.  It's bad use to try to adapt one architecture to the other.  And making the transfer serialization dependant on one (or the other) architecture is even worse.  No professional protocol is written nowadays based on such premises.  Show the code, please!

Answer (score 2):

In programming, it is not uncommon to need to treat network transmissions as separate from in-memory handling. In fact, it is pretty much the norm. So converting it to a network format of the proper byte order and size is really recommended and while help with the abstractions for your interfaces.

You might as well consider transforming to plain text, if that is not a time-critical piece of data exchange. It makes for a lot easier debugging.

Comment: Yes, normally I will never send structs, but I do not want to waste time to convert it. Best will be all Pi's will have exactly the some time to the last nanosecond. I know it is hard or not realizable, because of changing network roundtrip time but should be nearly as same as possible

Answer (score -3):

C is probably not the best tool for the job here. It's much too low level to provide automatic data serialization like JavaScript, Python or similar more abstract languages.

You cannot assume the definitions of `timespec` will be identical on different platforms. For one thing the size of an int will be different depending on the 32/64 bits architecture, and you can have endianing problems too.

When you want to exchange data structures between heterogeneous platforms, you need to define your own protocol with unambiguous data and a clear endianing convention.

One solution would be to send the numbers as ASCII. Not terribly efficient, but if it's just a couple of values, who cares?

Another would be to create an exchange structure with (u)intXX_t fields.
You can assume a standard raspberry kernel will be little endian like your PC, but if you're writing a small exchange protocol, you might as well add a couple of `htonl/ntohl` for good measure.

Comment: First I wrote a python script to sync the clients but the time value variation was to big... so I start to writing it in C, to get more control about the program. The time should be as identical as possible, because we want to realize a indoor navigation with sound. Otherwise I would use only a ntp-server.

Comment: I very doubt Python is the culprit here. Python is not "slow" enough to cause noticeable transmission delays (i.e. superior to 10 ms). Most probably one or both of your programs get stuck doing other things while the exchanged data are waiting to be processed. If you want to process whatever data in real time, you'd rather create a daemon with high priority on both machines so that each message is processed as soon as it is received. Whatever language the daemons run in will not make any noticeable difference.

Comment: The python scripts ran on fifo level 98 and got them own core and the script done nothing else as measure roundtrip time and set new time. To get the network delay on a nearly same level all Pi's connected to a switch. Most time it works fine, but not every time. I only want to get more control about thing happen, so I move to C... also very interesting what python and js abstract.

Comment: It is called serialisation. And he wanted to avoid it

Comment: Aha... And my answer is that it's impossible in C. Does that justify a downvote in your book?

Comment: @CordlessWool tinkering with FIFO priority will only make the actual transmission faster in case some other data are waiting to be sent. What you need is to change the priority of your Python script (with `nice`or whatever scheduler API) so that it will not get preempted by whatever other processes. Also you need to make your script a daemon, i.e. a single program that runs continuously, instead of launching a whole process each time you want to send a couple of bytes. If something is eating up time here, it's either the process launching or whatever other things running on your raspberry.

Comment: @kuroineko What kind of fifo do you mean? I meant fifo scheduling, which is on a much higher level as the nice value. With the nice value you only influence the priority of normal scheduling, but the fifo levels are higher then normal scheduling. All other program will run after programs that added to fifo scheduling. But all in all it is not needed, because I gave the script a hole core. And it was also run continuously all 10 sec in endless loop.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-cpu-scheduler.html

Comment: well, there are too many variables in your problem. At any rate, you should measure your sender process execution time to see if Python is really eating up so much time. I can't see how it would, but that's the first thing to do to make sure your C program has a chance to make things better.